# PhantomJS with Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, phantomjs

I know it sounds basic but I'd really appreciate some help/guidence on how to use phantomjs on my wordpress project. I'm using Windows 8.1 and local host with xampp for now. I've downloaded phantomjs and already tested it via command prompt and got the result (pdf) I want. Now I'd like to use it on my WP project but not sure how to get it started. I've tried to copy phantomjs folder to my wp-content/plugins folder and run exec command but no results at all.

I know there're lots of examples out there on how to run phantomjs but I couldn't find anything for wp.

Comment: What operating system is used on your server? Do you have access to the similar command prompt on the server? Please update the question with this information.

Comment: @Vaviloff I'm using XAMPP Server on my local machine which is running Windows 8.1

Comment: So you want to control PhantomJS from WP and do it in the future on XAMPP only?

Comment: @Vaviloff no. Right now, its on xampp so that i can test it. then it will go to a live server. probably linux. Right now we r using shared hosting but I'm thinking about seperate hosting for phantomjs

Comment: Please, elaborate on how you want to use it on your WP project.